# How can I boot Windows at external hard drive from internal hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot, external-hard-drive

In my internal hard drive, there is a copy of Windows installed at 'sda1'. I use grub to boot into it.

In my external hard drive (internal hard drive with a box), I have a complete Windows installed normally while the hard drive was in the computer.

Now, I want to use "Windows Boot Manager" to boot the external hard drive.

How can I find the Windows in the external hard drive?

Comment: How is the external drive connected? eSATA ?

Comment: @Hennes, USB. eSATA? Not sure, but I can "boot" from it (available for choice in BIOS) but I can't boot from it. (Can't enter Windows from it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the external drive is in a USB enclosure, then there is no way to boot Windows 7 from it.  Windows does not support booting from a USB drive even if the BIOS does.  It's not a GRUB or boot loader thing.  Windows 7 just doesn't support running from USB period.

Comment: "Windows just doesn't support running from USB period." Really? I must be [imagining things](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_To_Go) then. :) (Obviously W2G won't help the OP, but just mentioned it to show that your statement is incorrect.)

Comment: I actually knew about W2G, but that's a Win8 enterprise only feature. I added a '7' to my answer to make it more clear because that's the version the OP is on. If you wanna get real pedantic, Win7 can be hacked to boot from USB too (Win7 Embedded does it).  But honestly, as far as @Jamie is concerned it's not possible given his/her level of technical sophistication -- which is OK; that's what this site is for after all.  I just didn't mention it because I felt it's irrelevant information that might have just confused the OP more.

Comment: Once I had a Windows 7 in external (USB) hard drive, I boot from internal hard drive, I go to windows boot menu, I select Windows 7 Ultimate, I boot into external hard drive. What's the problem here?

Comment: @WesSayeed: Yes I know Win7 can be hacked but Win8 Enterprise doesn't need to be. Your edit makes the answer accurate now with respect to what's officially supported.

Comment: @Jamie: Are you sure you ran Win7 from a USB drive without hacking it in any way? How did the boot menu show what was on the external drive?

Comment: @Karan not so sure, but I was able to choose it. Btw, how to "hack" it?

Comment: @Jamie: I don't have the links at hand but of course there are detailed tutorials available on other sites.